# Adding Bootstrap Margin

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

This seems so simple, but I can't seem to get it to work.  All I want is to apply spacing between the right side of the screen and the four wide column I have created.  I have tried adding:

```
.spacer{
    margin-right: 2%;
}
```

onto a containing div unsuccessfully.  I have it working on my eight wide column but I can't seem to replicate it.  Jfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/fru2yv1f/

```
<div class="col-lg-12">
    <div class="row row-top">
        <div class="col-lg-8">
            <div class="horizontal-spacer text-center border-green">
                <div class="vert-center">
                    <h1 id="page-two-heading">Page two Heading</h1>
                    <p id="page-two-sub-heading">Information that is useful, hopefully!</p>
                </div>
            </div>
    </div>
        <div id="side-text" class="col-lg-4 hidden-md hidden-sm hidden-xs border-green">
            <div class="vert-center">
            <h3>This Area Will Disappear on Screen Resize</h3>
            <p>text text text text text text text texttext text text text text text text texttext text text text text text text texttext text text text text text text texttext text text text text text text texttext text text text text text text texttext text text text text text text texttext text text text text text text text</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: what are the labels for the four wide columns (id/class too)

Comment: Check out the question.  Added relevant html

Answer (score 1):

The solution was to add a class to the div with class col-lg-12 and then style the div with padding-right: 2%;

Ex.

```
<div class="col-lg-12 spacer">

.spacer{
  padding-right: 2%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Give the margin to the `vert-center`. Actually you are using all the 12 columns of the bootstrap grid and when you are adding `margin-right` to the div having `col-lg-4` it is exceeding the total width of the 12 columns and hence not working properly.

**example snippet**

```css
.vert-center {
margin-right: 2%;
}
```

```html
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="col-lg-12">
    <div class="row row-top">
        <div class="col-lg-8">
            <div class="horizontal-spacer text-center border-green">
                <div class="vert-center">
                    <h1 id="page-two-heading">Page two Heading</h1>
                    <p id="page-two-sub-heading">Information that is useful, hopefully!</p>
                </div>
            </div>
    </div>
        <div id="side-text" class="col-lg-4 hidden-md hidden-sm hidden-xs border-green">
            <div class="vert-center">
            <h3>This Area Will Disappear on Screen Resize</h3>
            <p>text text text text text text text texttext text text text text text text texttext text text text text text text texttext text text text text text text texttext text text text text text text texttext text text text text text text texttext text text text text text text texttext text text text text text text text</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: This only moves the contents of the Div.  Looking to move the div as a whole.